# request.POST not being picked up in django

Tags: python, django

I am using apiary to send API calls via POST. The method being sent is `POST` and it's sending the corret `POST DATA`, but django is not picking it up in the `request.POST` dict:

```
# this is printing request.method, request.body
[remote IP:43306] POST b'{\\n    "email": "tomas@gmail.com",\\n    "password": "hellopassword"\\n}'

# this is printing request.POST
[pid 4974:tid 140607472903936] [remote 54.81.191.72:43306] 333 POST <QueryDict: {}>
```

Why can't django properly parse the POST data here?

Comment: Because you are sending JSON, not form data.

Answer (score 0):

Check request.data instead.

request.POST is normally only present when posting a form. Technically, it's only present when the content type header is form encoded e.g. 'multipart/form-data'